# Unable to get current WordPress user information outside `wp-content`

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a file in some directory outside `wp-content` where I load the default WordPress file to run the following code. Lets say the file can be accessed using `domain.com/folder/user_info.php`.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once(__DIR__."/../wp-load.php");
require_once(__DIR__."/../wp-config.php");

$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
var_dump(wp_get_current_user());
```

When file is placed here, the output is:

```
object(WP_User)#2555 (8) { ["data"]=> object(stdClass)#3303 (0) { } ["ID"]=> int(0) ["caps"]=> array(0) { } ["cap_key"]=> NULL ["roles"]=> array(0) { } ["allcaps"]=> array(0) { } ["filter"]=> NULL ["site_id":"WP_User":private]=> int(0) }
```

When I place the same file inside `wp-content` and access it using `domain.com/wp-content/user_info.php`, I can get the information about the current user just fine.

The problem is that I don't want to put my own files inside `wp-content`. So, is there any way to get the information of logged in user outside the `wp-content` directory?

Thanks.

UPDATE:

This is my directory structure:

```
domain/
    wp-content/
        user_info.php
    wp-includes/
    wp-admin/
    custom-folder/
        user_info.php
```

The code is exactly the same in both `user_info` files. However, the file inside `wp-content` prints the user information but the file inside `custom-folder` does not.

Comment: What is the error you encountered?

Comment: Make sure that your `require_once` statement points to a correct path, also notice that `__DIR__` points to the current script's directory.

Comment: Before the plugins_loaded action it returns 0. - https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/plugins_loaded/

Comment: @JordanLipana I don't encounter any errors. The user just comes out with `id` 0 which is no existent.

Comment: @Kradyy Yes, they are pointing to the right path. I have many other scripts which do not need the user information in same directory and they work just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test your code, and it's working fine on my end.

Try the alternate:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

require_once(__DIR__."/../wp-load.php");
require_once(__DIR__."/../wp-config.php");

$connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

global $current_user;
var_dump($current_user);
```

Comment: Where did you put this file Jordan? :)

Comment: I am adding my own directory structure to the question.

Comment: I created a file in the root on my folder. Outside the `wp-content` folder. Example domain/sample.php